# Mongoose - Search inside nested array with no limits

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My mongodb collection is stores records of groups which can have subgroups, which can further have sub-sub groups and there will not be any limits of nesting of this sub-groups. Is there anyway in mongoose to find a group name that resides in nth level?

My collection structure looks like the following, so suppose if i want to find if "My Group" has a subgroup named "My Group 1001", how am I supposed to find it?

```
{
      "id": "60c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
      "name": "My Group",
      "subgroups": [
        {
              "id": "70c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
              "name": "My Group 2",
              "subgroups": [
                {
                      "id": "80c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
                      "name": "My Group 3",
                      "subgroups": [
                          {
                                "id": "90c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
                                "name": "My Group 4",
                                "subgroups": [ ... ],
                          }

                      ]
                }

              ]
        }

      ]
}
```

The other solutions that I found on stackoverflow suggested that it can be achieved using the dot notation for eg,

```
$or: [
  {"name": "My Group 1001"},
  {"subgroups.name": "My Group 1001"},
  {"subgroups.subgroups.name": "My Group 1001"},
  ...
]
```

But since in my case the level is not known hence I cannot use the above pattern.

Comment: You supposed to design your schema to support your queries. This one does not. Do what the other suggested - build your $or array programmatically with reasonable level of nested documents. There is a hard limit of 16MB per document so there is no truly "unlimited" nested arrays.

Comment: 16mb is a huge number to store texual data. When I say "unlimited", i mean there will be an unknown number of nesting, perhaps 10, 20, 50, 500. And even if there are 500 level of nesting, it will still be under 16 mb because the content is all text.

Comment: Fair enough. 500 $or conditions would be quite extreme query. I have put some recommendations in my answer.

Comment: If you were to design a schema that has such a requirement, how would you design it? I am not sure if my schema design is efficient hence need your inputs.

Comment: I already gave my recommendations regarding schema changes in my answer starting from words "If you have luxury of changing data format". A more radical change could be one of described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/ Please read the small print, there are limitations to keep in mind. And of course there is a whole world of specialised graph databases which were purposeful designed to store tree-like data structures if you fill adventurous.

Comment: Yes you have mentioned your recommendations, so according to you my db schema is good enough (if I added a top level "names" flat array of all names from the nested documents), and you would have also designed the same schema for such use case? Because I am also thinking if, instead of storing the subgroups as nested documents, would it have been better if I had stored the groups and subgroups in the same collection and each document would have a parentId that represents the parent-child relationship. Thoughts?

Comment: Schema design really depends on how you gonna use the data. The parent/child referencing + $graphLookup is one of the options. It is described in the mongodb blogpost I referred above. You won't have have the tree structure tho. You will need to build it up on the application level if you need the structure as in the OP. On the other hand it would be much simpler to update subdocuments. I'm afraid I can only repeat my original stanza - write down typical queries you gonna have and design schema to support these queries.

Comment: If I had working application and had to add the feature to search across all subdocuments I would go with the extra "names" field. It is least intrusive change and does not require massive refactoring. The downside is if documents are changed manually they may have outdated "names". As I said mongo is not the best tool for tree structures so any design will be a compromise. It's your call what option to chose. You know your application and business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb is not an ideal tool for recursive operations.

**Not recommended**, but you can use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) to do the job with javascript:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $function: {
      body: "function(subgroups, topName) { let recursiveSearch = function(sg){ if(!sg) {return false}; return sg.some(function(subdoc) {return subdoc.name == 'My Group 1001' || recursiveSearch(subdoc.subgroups)})}; return topName == 'My Group 1001' || recursiveSearch(subgroups);}",
      args: [
        "$subgroups",
        "$name"
      ],
      lang: "js"
    }
  }
})
```

The function alone formatted for readability:

```
function(subgroups, topName) {
    let recursiveSearch = function (sg) {
        if (!sg) { return false };
        return sg.some(function (subdoc) {
            return subdoc.name == 'My Group 1001' || recursiveSearch(subdoc.subgroups)
        })
    }; 
    return topName == 'My Group 1001' || recursiveSearch(subgroups);
}
```

There is no tail recursion so I imagine it may blow up if it exhaust call stack. Didn't test it myself though.

If you have luxury of changing data format, consider adding a top level "names" flat array of all names from the nested documents. It will add some overhead to the application logic to keep it up to date on each update. The search will be as simple as

```
db.collection.find({"names": "My Group 1001"})
```

As an additional bonus you will be able to benefit from [multikey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe finding keys with values can help you:

```js
const flattenObj = (obj, parent, res = {}) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    let propName = parent ? parent + '.' + key : key;
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      flattenObj(obj[key], propName, res);
    } else {
      res[propName] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return res;
}


const obj = {
  "id": "60c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
  "name": "My Group",
  "subgroups": [
    {
      "id": "70c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
      "name": "My Group 2",
      "subgroups": [
        {
          "id": "80c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
          "name": "My Group 3",
          "subgroups": [
            {
              "id": "90c18d4ce973fc139f23bf93",
              "name": "My Group 4"
            }

          ]
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}

const dotNotation = flattenObj(obj);

// Finding keys from object by a specific value
const key1 = Object.keys(dotNotation).find(key => dotNotation[key] === 'My Group 2');
const key2 = Object.keys(dotNotation).find(key => dotNotation[key] === 'My Group 3');
const key3 = Object.keys(dotNotation).find(key => dotNotation[key] === 'My Group 4');

console.log(`Key of 'My Group 2': ` + key1);
console.log(`Key of 'My Group 3': ` + key2);
console.log(`Key of 'My Group 4': ` + key3);
```

Comment: Does mongodb/mongoose put a limit how many data is populated per page or does it impose a limit on depth of nesting?

Comment: You can use `$project` to limit returning data. Use my answer to get key names and unselect the fields you don't want to get.

Comment: I understand the $project part, but my original question was does mongodb, by default, put any limit to nesting depth and number of pages shown at once?

Meaning, if i have 100000 documents in my user collection, and  if i run User.findAll({}), will it return 100000 documents at once?